# Access a mailer method without sending the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have a working mailer in Rails 3.

I want to have some logic inside the mailer methods which will decide if to email it or not. 
I cannot have this logic outside the mailer, since I am using `Delayed_job` with a delay. I delay the email for an hour. If a condition hasn't been met, I send the email.

**1. Is there a way to enter the mailer method and not complete the sending (gracefully)**

**2. Is there a better way of achieve what I am trying?**

**Code Sample**

This is the mailer

```
class MessagesMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def message_notification(user, message)
    @user = user
    @msg = message
    mail(to: @user.email, from: "#{@msg.sender.name} <me@myapp.com>", subject: "You have recieved a new message from #{@msg.sender.name}")
  end
end
```

`MessagesMailer.delay(:run_at => 5.minutes.from_now).message_notification(@user, @message)` is being called throughout the app, particularly from `MessagesController`

I want to check if `@user` has already read that message. If so, not send the email. 
`Delay_job` would perform `message_notification` in 5 minutes, but once that method is complete the email is sent regardless of what happens inside of it.

Is there a way to cancel delivery upon a condition (`@user` read the message)?

Comment: could you show us the code so far? i did not understand the problem.

Comment: I added a more specific example, thanks

Comment: Any reason you are not using (or can't) a custom job for this?

Comment: what do you mean by custom?

Comment: You can create a custom job class and put all the functionality you want in there. You can use DJ outside of the provided `delay` method.

Comment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs